# Does a pointer returned by std::string.c_str() or std::string.data() have to be freed?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

As far as I know, `std::string` creates an identical array-copy of its content when you call the `c_str()`/`data()` methods (with or without the terminating NUL-char; it does not matter here). Anyway, does the object also take care of freeing this array or do I have to?

In short:

```
std::string hello("content");

const char* Ptr = hello.c_str();

// Use it....

delete[] Ptr;   //// Really ???
```

I just want to be on the safe side when it comes to memory allocation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need to deallocate the `ptr` pointer.

`ptr` points to a nonmodifiable string located somewhere to an *internal location* (actually, this is an implementation detail of the compilers).

---

Reference:

**[C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)**:

```
const char* c_str ( ) const;
```

Get C string equivalent

Generates a null-terminated sequence of characters (c-string) with the same content as the string object and returns it as a pointer to an array of characters.

A terminating null character is automatically appended.

**The returned array points to an internal location with the required storage space for this sequence of characters plus its terminating null-character, but the values in this array should not be modified in the program and are only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object.**

Comment: until now, i just knowed about static and dynamic memory. i bet "non-modifyable string" lies in somewhere between.

Comment: You are correct, `ptr` does not need to be (and, in fact, must not be) freed. And, the nature of that pointer is implementation-defined. However, that pointer almost certainly points to dynamic memory in the  free store, and almost certainly does not point to static read-only memory.

Comment: @Rob: And that statement is almost certainly wrong for some version of the STL. (especially the variants that are implementing the small string optimization).

Comment: What part of this is copied from elsewhere (if any)? Those parts must be *** *** ***clearly marked*** *** *** (quoted) as such. Otherwise, it is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun). See e.g. *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think it comes from the linked C++ documentation but they reworded it.

Answer (score 4):

*std::string* handles this pointer, so don't release it. Moreover, there are two limitations on using this pointer:

1. Don't modify the string that is pointed by this pointer; it is read-only.
2. This pointer may become invalid after calling other *std::string* methods.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any need. The destructor of the string class will handle the destruction of the string, so when 'hello' goes out of scope, it is freed.

Answer (score 0):

Not only don't you need to free the pointer, but you in fact *should not*. Otherwise, the destructor of `std::string` will attempt to free it again which may result in various errors depending on the platform.

Comment: it compiled without any crashed on my system but you're right. Nevertheless, i think that the d'tor will check the pointer before freeing it.

Comment: it's not "should not", but "must not". Doing so is an error, always and in all cases.

Comment: @Florian: the destructor won't (and can't) "check the pointer".

Comment: @BeschBesch
 this would generate a runtime memory leak not a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::string` class is responsible for freeing the memory allocated to contain the characters of the string when an object of the class is destructed. So if you do

```
delete[] Ptr;
```

before or after `hello` object is destructed (leaves the C++ `{}` scope it was created in), your program will run into a problem of trying to free a memory block that is already freed.